# Get images with selectbox on user submit

Tags: php, forms, user-input

Hi guys I need some typical information about php

I am creating a selectbox which have multiple option . and i have 6 images as well then i need when user select 1 ,2 ,3 and submit then image1, image2, image3 have to show on page and when user select 2, 4, 6 and submit then image2, image4, image6 have to show so what i do in php to get this code i trid so much buut no luck help me out thanks.

```
   <form method="get">
        <select name="images" multiple="multiple">
            <option name="img" value="image">1</option>
            <option name="img" value="image">2</option>
            <option name="img" value="image">3</option>
            <option name="img" value="image">4</option>
            <option name="img" value="image">5</option>
            <option name="img" value="image">6</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

here is php

```
<?php
//path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a subdirectory
$directory = "images/*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

//shuffle array
shuffle($imgs);

//select first 20 images in randomized array
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);

//display images
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
echo "<img src='$img' /> ";
}
?>
```

but i want this work on submit thanks

Comment: the values for all your options are the same `image`. This is what will be send to the server, so how are you going to detect what got selected by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reference user choices by naming of select field = "images[]"  exp:

```
<select name="images[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">1</option>
..
</select>
```

then in php you can access the submitted values $_GET['images']. It give you an array of submitted values in the order

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your php code with this 'if' statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 mistakes, you can continue from there:
1. in the form, you must include some action to the form - The name of the file that will open after the submission and will receive the data via $_GET.
2. you need to make a foreach - endforeach loop and print the data of the pictures instead of repeating the options rows...

It should look something like this:

```
<?php
//path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a subdirectory
$directory = "imagesend/*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

//shuffle array
shuffle($imgs);

//select first 20 images in randomized array
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);


?>
<form method="get" action="XXX.php">
<select name="images" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach ($imgs as $img):  ?>

<option name="<?php echo $img; ?>" value="<?php echo $img; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"/></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Listing 9.15 A file upload script</title>
 </head>
 <?php
if ( isset( $_POST['img']) )
 {
    $im="images/".$_POST['img'].".jpg";
    echo "".$im;
    echo "<img src='".$im ."'/>";
 }
 else
 {
     print "Error";
 }

 ?>
 <body>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
        <select name="img" multiple="multiple">
            <option  value="image1">1</option>
            <option  value="image2">2</option>
            <option  value="image3">3</option>
            <option  value="image4">4</option>
            <option  value="image5">5</option>
            <option  value="image6">6</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```